# Perl - SUPER - Can't locate object method

Tags: perl

I created following 2 files, but when I run sample.pl, its giving me the following error
`Can't locate object method "new" via package "sample" at sample.pm line 14.`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

```
package sample;

use strict;

sub new {
    my $proto = shift;
    my $class = ref($proto) || $proto;
    my %fields = (
                   Debug => 0,
                   Error => undef,
                   @_,
                );

    my $self = bless $proto->SUPER::new(%fields), $class;
    return $self;
}

1;
```

sample.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use sample;

my $obj = sample->new();

print "Howdy, sample\n";
```

Comment: Where do you have `ref($proto) || $proto` from?

Answer (score 3):

The pseudo-class `SUPER` refers to the parent class of the package it appears in (not the parent class of the object that calls it!). You have no parent class. Add a parent class to see it work. Here's an example with a few modifications.

```
#######################
package ParentSample;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my( $class, %fields ) = @_;
    # some debugging statements so you can see where you are:
    print "I'm in ", __PACKAGE__, " for $class\n";

    # make the object in only one class
    bless \%fields, $class;
    }

#######################
package Sample;
use strict;
use warnings;

use base qw(ParentSample);

sub new {
    my( $class ) = shift;
    # some debugging statements so you can see where you are:
    print "I'm in ", __PACKAGE__, " for $class\n";

    my %fields = (
                   Debug => 0,
                   Error => undef,
                );

    # let the parent make the object
    $class->SUPER::new( %fields );
}

#######################
package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $obj = Sample->new( cat => 'Buster' );

print "Howdy, sample\n";
```

Curiously, this error message got much better in recent versions of perl. Your old perl doesn't put `SUPER` in the message:

```
$ perl5.8.9 sample
Can't locate object method "new" via package "sample" at sample line 14.
$ perl5.10.1 sample
Can't locate object method "new" via package "sample" at sample line 14.
$ perl5.12.1 sample
Can't locate object method "new" via package "sample::SUPER" at sample line 14.
$ perl5.14.1 sample
Can't locate object method "new" via package "sample::SUPER" at sample line 14.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `use base` in your *sample.pm* file - it is not inheriting any other package - who do you expect `$proto->SUPER` to be?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using base you can also modity @ISA array and load module yourself:

So

```
use base "ParentSample";
```

could be replaced with:

```
require ParentSample;
@ISA = ("ParentSample");
```

When modifying @ISA, loading module is important otherwise it won't work. Base load's it for you.